# Linearlayout below scrollview not showing up

Tags: android, scrollview

The following should show a scrollview that takes up the entire screen except for a small portion large enough for a button at the bottom. When I run this the button/layout does not show up at all. Only the scrollview which takes up the entire screen with other views I have within the scrollview. Thoughts?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.th3ramr0d.armybodyfatcalculator.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
        />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout
```

Comment: this layout work but you need to defined maxHeight to your scroll view

Comment: I want the device to determine the size of the scrollview for me depending on the size of the layout below it. is that possible?

Comment: then consider @Tiago Oliveira answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the job for you

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     tools:context="com.th3ramr0d.armybodyfatcalculator.MainActivity"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     >
     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myButton">
     </ScrollView>

     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/myButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The outer LinearLayout is redundant, it's enough to just have RelativeLayout as the top element.

Comment: @Egor android recommends to avoid relativelayout as root layout, I just wanted to know if this will lead to any performance issue ?

Comment: updated, i never had problems using relativelayout as root

Comment: @dex, Can you please provide a source for this recommendation? There's also a performance overhead of having nested layouts, so usually the suggestion is to keep layouts as flat as possible - that's what ConstraintLayout actually tries to achieve.

Comment: Your answer has fixed my problem. I do understand the basics of relative layouts but I generally avoid them because I'm not very familiar with them. Guess it's time to go read some more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Egor https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-iii-2efc140167fd#.yo7blew2y this article is complied by Chet Haase

Comment: @dex Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: @dex Chet is definitely right, but the main takeaways in my opinion are that  1) you should avoid nesting RelativeLayouts and 2) you should not use RelativeLayout when you can avoid it. In OPs case RelativeLayout is a good solution and justifies its use, additionally, it only has two children, so the layout won't be super expensive. Wrapping it in a LinearLayout will certainly not make it faster.

Comment: @th3ramr0d, Take a look at ConstraintLayout while you're at it, there's a great Codelab that you can try: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Comment: @Egor thanks for detail explanation, I totally agree with you :)